# Repeating email notifications in Bosun

Tags: bosun

in notification of Bosun configuration, I set the timeout as 5m i.e. 5 minutes.
I am receiving emails for the interval of either 5 minutes or 10 minutes.
I am not able to debug as why is this happening.
Please help.

```
    notification default {
    email =jon@rohit.com
    print = true
    next = default
    timeout = 5m

}

template tags {
    subject =`Testing Emails Sample`
    body = `<p><strong>Tags</strong>

    <table>
        {{range $k, $v := .Group}}
            {{if eq $k "api"}}
                <tr><td>{{$k}} : {{$v}}</td></tr>
            {{end}}
        {{end}}
    </table>`
}




alert testSampleAlert5 {
    template = tags
    $notes = This alert monitors the percentage of 5XX on arm APIs


    crit =  1
    warn = 0
    warnNotification = default
    critNotification = default

}

alert testSampleAlert4 {
    template = tags
    $notes = This alert monitors the percentage of 5XX on arm APIs


    crit = 0
    warn = 1
    warnNotification = default
    critNotification = default

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are encountering is bosun's feature of "chained notifications". The `next` and `timeout` parameters specify that the `default` notification will be triggered again after 5 minutes as you have configured it. Since it references itself, it will trigger every 5 minutes until the alert is acknowledged or closed.

You have a few options if this is not what you want.

1. Acknowledge the alert on the dashboard. This will stop all notification chains from repeating.
2. Remove the `next` parameter if you do not want to be re-notified every 5 minutes, or increase the timeout, or something like that.

What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Hi, I expect notification for every 5 minutes. But, I am getting notifications sometimes in 5 minutes interval or sometimes in 10 minutes interval.